# How to (properly) trigger row filtering on demand?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have several addFilter(functionHandle) calls, but I want to trigger a filtering using all the current filters, on demand.

Right now, Im doing :

```js
removeFilter(undefined);
```

to trigger the filters to be applied, but one day if Tabulator.prototype.removeFilter() actually checks if the filter was there to be removed and doesnt call rowManager.filterRefresh(), I'll be SOL !

In the Row Management Pipeline, there is

> Filter Rows
> Apply all filters (programatic and header filters) and remove rows that do not match.

but is there a function call to trigger it ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear what you are looking for there.

Once filters have been applied they remain applied until they are removed, there is no need to "trigger" a filter again. You certainly shouldn't be trying to call functions on the prototype, just call them on the table instance itself.

#### Add Filter

If you want to add a filter to an existing filter set, you can use the ***addFilter*** function

```js
table.addFilter("age", ">", 22);
```

#### Replace Filter

if you want to replace the existing filters with a new filter, you can use the ***setFilter*** function:

```js
table.setFilter("age", ">=", 10);
```

#### Set Multiple Filters

If you want to set multiple filters simulations, you can pass an array of filter objects to the ***setFilter*** function:

```js
table.setFilter([
    {field:"age", type:">", value:52}, //filter by age greater than 52
    {field:"height", type:"<", value:142}, //and by height less than 142
    {field:"name", type:"in", value:["steve", "bob", "jim"]}, //name must be steve, bob or jim
]);
```

#### Remove Filter

If you want to remove a specific filter you can call the ***removeFilter*** function:

```js
table.removeFilter("age", ">", 22);
```

#### Clear All Filters

If you want to remove all filters you can call the ***clearFilter*** function

```js
table.clearFilter();
```

#### Retrigger the Same Filters

If you want to remove the existing filters and reapply them then you can use a combination of the ***getFilters*** function and the ***setFilter*** function:

```js
table.setFilter(table.getFilters());
```

Full details on how to use the filter module can be found in the [Filter Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/filter)

Comment: I have a customerFilter that uses an outside source of information within the filter. So when that changes, I need to trigger the filters

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. Do you have a JS fiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a "Retrigger the Same Filters" option, that retrieves the current filters and reapplies them

Comment: Is that going to be added to the Documentation, or am I not seeing it in there already ... or was it implied by the existence of the 2 functions already ?

Comment: The documentation already lists the available functions and their operations,it is down to developers to choose how to use them.